# ZoomIn and ZoomOut doesn't zoom from center with slider

Tags: jquery, d3.js

d3 force layout ZoomIn and ZoomOut  doesn't zoom from center with slider it starts from left to right. But when I use mouse wheel it zoom from center. Please check link `jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/aVhd8/206/`

Comment: Please add the code to your question too.

Comment: I have got an idea from this link http://computing.dcu.ie/~dganguly/d3sliderzoom.htm

Comment: the link you just provided is exactly what i provided in the answer

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you'ddo it with mousewheel

```
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
.center([width / 2, height / 2]) //centers zoom
     .scaleExtent([.1, 1])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);
```

Maybe that will get you started :)

Here is a link that may help too : http://bl.ocks.org/linssen/7352810

Comment: This is working fine for mouse wheel but when use slider its not working as mouse wheel. http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/aVhd8/206/